# How to send Activation code like *777# to dialer using an Intent?

Tags: java, android

I want to send code *777#  to dialer in android  using intent but i have a problem only *777 key code will be displayed on dialer not # how to resolve this issue  i'm new in android developer so please help me out this problem.

```
    String dialler_Code = "*777#";
    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    // Use format with "tel:" and phoneNumber created is stored in u.

    Uri u = Uri.parse("tel:" + dialler_Code);

    // Create the intent and set the data for the intent as the phone number.

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, u);
      try {
        // Launch the Phone app's dialer with a phone number to dial a call.
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (SecurityException s) {

        // show() method display the toast with exception message.
        Toast.makeText(this, s.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: its just typing mistake thanks @John Douma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `String dialler_Code = Uri.encode("*777#");`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this : **

```
String enCodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

String number = "*151*1" + enCodedHash;

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ number));
startActivity(callIntent);
```